# How to list all possible packages / modules in AOSP via command line?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-soong, android-make

In AOSP, I often use the following to setup my environment and build target and build the entire image:

```
$ cd ~/aosp
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk_phone_x86_64
$ m
```

I also like to use the following to build a specific package/module instead of the entire image:

```
$ m <my package>
```

or

```
$ cd <path_to_package>
$ mm
```

Is there a way to simply list all possible packages/modules in all of AOSP? Similar to how running `lunch` displays all possible targets, I'm interested in seeing a list of all possible packages/modules (e.g. defined in Android.bp and Android.mk).

Follow up question: given a package/module name, is there a way to get the directory or path to the file that defines it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build/make/envsetup.sh has define the shell function:

```
- allmod:     List all modules.
- pathmod:    Get the directory containing a module.
```